# php compare string result

Tags: php, comparison, if-statement

how do i compare the with if else statement. in mysql query i can use `LIKE %` statement.
i want to compare the string result with php.
ie: Pro Tan 3mins, Pro Tan 6mins, Pro Tan 9mins

in mysql :

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM treat WHERE tanning LIKE 'Pro Tan%'");
```

in php:

```
if($tanning == 'Pro Tan') :
  echo 'xxx';
else :
  echo 'zzz';
endif
// output zzz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a variety of different comparison functions you can use, depending on how sophisticated you want to make your comparison. To find specifically a string that starts with "Pro Tan", you could do:

```
if (strpos($tanning, 'Pro Tan') === 0)
    echo 'xxx';
```

Note the triple `===`, since if `strpos` returns `false`, that's not at all the same as returning `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the result begins with the value, you can use [`strncmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strncmp.php).

```
$foo = 'Pro Tan 6mins';
if (strncmp($foo,'Pro Tan', 7) === 0)
  echo 'match';
```

For case-insensative, you can also use [`strncasecmp`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strncasecmp.php).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [`strstr()` function in PHP](http://php.net/strstr), which allows you to search for a string within a string.

```
if(strstr($tanning, 'Pro Tan')):
  echo 'xxx';
else :
  echo 'zzz';
endif;
```

Comment: Perhaps, but in the SQL example it's not matching ANYWHERE in the string, it's matching specifically at the beginning.

Comment: True. My method is more greedy!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(preg_match("/^Pro Tan/",$foo)) {....}
```

Other answers given will also work, but regular expressions using `preg_match()` is more flexible and will continue to work with more complex matching.

(some will say that regex is slow, but in this case, since it's just matching a straight string anchored to the start, it's a very efficient query)